# Why does request.getCharacterEncoding() return null?

Tags: java, jsp, encoding

I have the following code in JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
```

and also in web.xml I have a filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when I add `request.getCharacterEncoding()` to check the encoding, it returns null.

Is there anyone who has  experience about this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you 'add' `request.getCharacterEncoding()`, in the JSP?

Comment: @home: In an Action there is a method handling the request, i put the code in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP directive refers to **responses**.

Similarly, a quick Google for "chracterencoding filter spring" returned [this forum thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?14063-How-to-set-setCharacterEncoding-on-Request).